# Submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with tangent space spanned by given vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, submanifold

**Question:** This is part of a problem from an old qualifying exam that I am having a little trouble with, so any help is greatly appreciated! In the problem, we are given two vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ expressed by
$$X = x(2y + \cos(y))\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial}{\partial z},\qquad Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} $$
and we need to write down a submanifold $N$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing the point $p = (0,1,0)$ such that there is an open neightborhood $U_p$ around $p$ such that for every point $q\in U_p$ we have $T_qN = \text{span}\{X\vert_q, Y\vert_q\}$, but I can't figure out a good way of going about this.

**My Attempt:** My first thought was to check and see if $X$ and $Y$ commute: they are obviously linearly independent at $p = (0,1,0)$, so if they commute, there is some coordinate representation of $N = (s^1,s^2,s^3)$ such that for a chart $(V_p, (s^i))$ of $N$ centered at $p$, we have that $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial s^1}$ and $Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial s^2}$ [see Theorem 9.46 of Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds]. However, when I compute the Lie bracket $[X, Y]$, I get
$$\begin{align*}
[X,Y] &= X(1)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + X(1)\frac{\partial}{\partial z} - Y(x(2y + \cos(y)))\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + Y(1)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
&=0 + 0 - (2x-x\sin(y))\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+0\\
&=(x\sin(y) - 2x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
&\not= 0,
\end{align*}$$
so the vector fields don't commute. At this point I got stuck. I did compute that the flow $\theta_t$ of $X$ is given by 
$$\theta_t(x,y,z) = (xe^{2yt + t\cos(y)}, y, z - t),$$
and that the flow $\psi_t$ of $Y$ is given by
$$\psi_t(x,y,z) = (x, y + t, z + t),$$
but I don't really know how to use this information to describe $N$.

Comment: I guess you mean for every $q \in U_p \cap N$ the condition about the tangential space should hold?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\theta'^{p}(t)=X_{\theta^{p}(t)},$ and $\psi'^{p}(t)=Y_{\psi^{p}(t)},$ so using your calculation,  i.e. $\theta_t(0,1,0) = (0,1,-t)$ and $\psi_t(0,1,0) = (0, 1 + t, t),$ we get a vector normal to a desired submanifold by taking the cross-product: $X_{\theta_t(0,1,0)}\times Y_{\psi_t(0,1,0)}=(1,0,0)$, and it follows now that $N$ is the $yz$-plane.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much! That also helps me out with a later part of the question.